# Using select for packet sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, select

Is it possible to use select for packet sockets? I mean whether its necessary for the socket to be connection-based in order to use select function on it properly?
I'm seeing that the behavior of a socket which I got it by the following socket function call:

```
int socket_fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

is not as I expect. For example, I see that a ping packet which is 60 bytes long when received and read into a 20 bytes length buffer, it waits about a second between each recv function call. I used recvfrom and it didn't help. For this, I ask whether it's correct to use select for a packet socket?

### Update

I'm going to include the code to discuss about it:

```
int MakeBridge(const char *if1, const char *if2)
{
    int sock[2];
    sock[0] = OpenSocket(if1);
    sock[1] = OpenSocket(if2);
    int activity;
    char buf[20];
    const int numSocks = 2;
    int nfds = sock[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numSocks; i++)
        if (sock[i] > nfds)
            nfds = sock[i];
    nfds++;
    while (true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        for (int i = 0; i < numSocks; i++)
            FD_SET(sock[i], &readfds);
        activity = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (activity == -1)  // sockets closed
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < numSocks; i++)
            if (FD_ISSET(_sock[i], &readfds))
            {
                int len;
                CHECK(ioctl(_sock[i], FIONREAD, &len) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));
                printf("socket %d is set\n", i);
                printf("total bytes available to read: %d\n", len);
                CHECK(len > 0, "");
                do
                {
                    int n = min(len, sizeof(buf));
                    int nbr = recvfrom(_sock[i], buf, n, 0, NULL, NULL);
                    printf("n %d nbr %d\n", n, nbr);
                    CHECK(n == nbr, "");
                    len -= n;
                } while (len);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Update 2

Not going to segment messages and using large enough buffer makes the code as follows:

```
// This is a program which is going to make the bridge between two interfaces. brctl is going to be replaced by this program.

#define Uses_CHECK
#define Uses_close
#define Uses_errno
#define Uses_ETH_P_ALL
#define Uses_FD_SET
#define Uses_htons
#define Uses_ifreq
#define Uses_ioctl
#define Uses_printf
#define Uses_signal
#define Uses_sockaddr_ll
#define Uses_socket
#define Uses_strerror
#include <general.dep>

int _sock[2];

int _CtrlCHandler()
{
    printf(" terminating...\n");
    CHECK(close(_sock[0]) != -1, "");
    CHECK(close(_sock[1]) != -1, "");
    printf("all sockets closed successfully.\n");
}

void CtrlCHandler(int dummy)
{
    _CtrlCHandler();
}

int OpenSocket(const char *ifname)
{
    // getting socket
    int socket_fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW/*|SOCK_NONBLOCK*/, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    CHECK(socket_fd != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));

    // init interface options struct with the interface name
    struct ifreq if_options;
    memset(&if_options, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_options.ifr_name, ifname, sizeof(if_options.ifr_name) - 1);
    if_options.ifr_name[sizeof(if_options.ifr_name) - 1] = 0;

    // enable promiscuous mode
    CHECK(ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &if_options) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));
    if_options.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    CHECK(ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &if_options) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));

    // get interface index
    CHECK(ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_options) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));

    // bind socket to the interface
    struct sockaddr_ll my_addr;
    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    my_addr.sll_ifindex = if_options.ifr_ifindex;
    CHECK(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));

    // socket is ready
    return socket_fd;
}

int MakeBridge(const char *if1, const char *if2)
{
    _sock[0] = OpenSocket(if1);
    CHECK_NO_MSG(_sock[0]);
    _sock[1] = OpenSocket(if2);
    CHECK_NO_MSG(_sock[1]);
    printf("sockets %d and %d opened successfully\n", _sock[0], _sock[1]);

    fd_set readfds, orig;
    int activity;
    char buf[1<<16];
    signal(SIGINT, CtrlCHandler);
    int packetNumber = 0;
    const int numSocks = _countof(_sock);
    int nfds = _sock[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numSocks; i++)
        if (_sock[i] > nfds)
            nfds = _sock[i];
    nfds++;
    FD_ZERO(&orig);
    for (int i = 0; i < numSocks; i++)
        FD_SET(_sock[i], &orig);
    while (true)
    {
        readfds = orig;
        activity = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (activity == -1)  // sockets closed
            break;
        CHECK(activity > 0, "");
        for (int i = 0; i < numSocks; i++)
            if (FD_ISSET(_sock[i], &readfds))
            {
                int len = recvfrom(_sock[i], buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_TRUNC, NULL, NULL);
                CHECK(len > 0, "");
                CHECK(len <= sizeof(buf), "small size buffer");
                printf("%10d %d %d\n", ++packetNumber, i, len);
                CHECK(sendto(_sock[!i], buf, len, 0, NULL, 0) == len, "");
            }
    }

    return 0;
}

int Usage(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("Usage: %s <if1> <if2>\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Bridges two interfaces with the names specified.\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
        return Usage(argc, argv);
    CHECK_NO_MSG(MakeBridge(argv[1], argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the socket non-blocking?

Comment: I can assure you that select works fine on UDP, which is not connection-oriented.

Comment: Do note that on a datagram-oriented socket, reading a 60 byte packet into a 20 byte buffer is an error

Comment: @David: Yes, but it gets worse. I expect such a packet with length of 60 when read in a 20 bytes buffer, need three sequential recv, but first one reads 20 bytes and the second one returns -1! It seems that the remainder of the packet is lost! For this I changed non-blocking to blocking. Although when something is ready on the socket to be read, why do I need to wait? So blocking socket should also not wait.

Comment: Ben: Why? I append it to the previous buffer data in a larger buffer. Is it an error? I expect socket to work like a file for me. socket streams should not differ with file streams from this aspect, do they?

Comment: Indeed I'm going to read whatever received by the network interface. Assume that I'm implementing something like tcpdump.

Comment: " If a message is too long to
       fit  in  the supplied buffer, excess bytes may be discarded depending on the type of socket the message
       is received from." Maybe use buffers larger than the maximum message size?

Comment: Oh really?! From what man page did you got it? Besides, how can I know what will be the maximum packet length? I can't predict it. So, I've to allocate a normal size buffer and process it as the data gets complete.

Comment: @hamidi That's from the man page for `recv`. The problem with what you're doing is that it loses the message boundaries. For message-oriented protocols, the `recv` function receives a message. Such protocols always have a maximum message length and you should use a buffer at least that large.

Comment: Assume there're two network cards and I just need to write a program to work like a bridge, so that it gets whatever it receives from one and send that dumbly to the other and this happens for both cards. In such a case, I've not to worry about the buffer size I've allocated, nor processing it.

Comment: @hamidi Huh? If you lose the message boundaries because you don't know whether you got two 40-byte packets or one 80-byte packet, how can that possibly work? For that application, you absolutely *must* use a buffer at least as large as the largest message.

Comment: Since payload may vary dynamically, how can I decide about the buffer size?

Comment: Use a buffer at least as large as the largest message size supported by the protocol you're bridging. Every message protocol has a maximum message size.

Comment: If you mean I've to adjust a minimum size, what's the size? Otherwise, I can't have any idea about the packet the network card will receive.

Comment: If you're bridging IP, the maximum packet size is 65,535.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that every message protocol has a maximum message size. Linux kernels may decide about increasing and decreasing packet size dynamically to reduce the overhead. Does this maximum have a limit? And for me to support all kinds of packets, what should be this maximum?

Comment: I'm not only going to bridge IP, but also everything else. ie. ARP, DNS, ICMP, UDP, etc. everything.

Comment: @hamidi take a look at the laypout of the IP header. (you'll need to understand that anyway if you want  to bridge packets/segments)

Comment: When using wireshark, I see that packets are segmented and sent via two or more separate packets. So, dividing them into parts should not be an error. So, I've not to worry about too large packets, should I?

Comment: At the moment, I've done tcpdump and I create pcap file which is readable by wireshark by not using libpcap and just reading the packets directly from the socket.

Comment: Now I'm going to implement bridge to pass everything between two cards.

Comment: I added the code I wrote to discuss about it. If I use `sizeof(buf)` instead of `n` as the third argument to recvfrom, nbr will be the same value as sizeof(buf)! This is weird, because those much bytes are not ready on the socket! How is it possible?!

Comment: Based on what you said, I'm going to modify my code not to split messages into parts and use a 64k buffer for recv and send.

Comment: Done. Please review the code and see where I'm not acting correctly. The bridge is not established yet.

Comment: @hamidi What's the issue with that code exactly? (Other than the race condition with `select` followed by a blocking `recvfrom`?)

Comment: Basically, it's a CTS Lab. st1 pings st3 via st2. The code runs on st2 to make the bridge. I see that st1 when pings st3, it doesn't receive its response. How can I make sure the point of corruption in the path?

Comment: I also couldn't figure out why there should be a race condition? recvfrom is not called until select is returned.

Comment: And another question, Is it a problem to replace recvfrom with recv and sendto with send?

Comment: I guess the problem is that in the next loop it receives what it had sent in the previous loop, although I've used select just for read.

Comment: weird! it's an old proverb that says, "reboot is an succedaneum for every unresolvable issue"! :D

Comment: Now in st1 with ip 192.168.2.1 I can ping st2 with ip 192.168.2.2 and vice versa. st2 has an additional network card which is of type bridge and can access internet via host's LAN. So, st2 may ping internet ips like 4.2.2.4, but st1 can't. Any idea?

Comment: oh it's ok. that was a mistake. nat in st3 had been deleted from iptables.

Comment: Now that everything is okay as far as IP is concerned, let's go to the next step. How can I resolve names in st1? :-)

Comment: It was easy. Just specify a DNS for 192.168.2.1 in st1.

Comment: Another problem arised, large packets can't be sent. Although they're not so large, eg. 2697 bytes long. Any clue?